# Can you write button function in suitelet instead of using client script?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Most examples involve calling a client script in suitelet and then the suitelet button calls a function in client script. I was wondering if u can write the button function in suitelet instead.. is it possible?
This is because I want to run n/task module which cannot be used in a client side script and has to be used in the suitelet.

An example would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the  form.addSubmitButton. when clicked it works on the post action and the task module can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to call a suitelet directly per your original question. If you want to avoid a client script just to have a function to call you can do:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/log", "N/search", "N/url"], function (log, search, url) {
    function beforeLoad(ctx) {
        var form = ctx.form;
        log.debug({ title: 'before load with ' + ctx.type, details: null });
        if (ctx.type == ctx.UserEventType.VIEW) {
            var ffRec = ctx.newRecord;
            if (ffRec.getValue({/* some logic that requires the action */})) {
                var orderStatus = search.lookupFields({
                    type: 'salesorder',
                    id: ffRec.getValue({ fieldId: 'createdfrom' }),
                    columns: [
                        'statusref'
                    ]
                }).statusref[0].value;
                if (orderStatus.indexOf('pendingBilling') != -1) {
                    var suiteletURL = url.resolveScript({
                        scriptId: 'customscript_my_script', 
                        deploymentId: 'customdeploy_my_script', 
                        returnExternalUrl: true
                    });
                    form.addButton({
                        id: 'custpage_button_1',
                        label: 'My Action',
                        functionName: '(function processRebill(){window.location.href=\"'+ suiteletURL + '&custparam_ff=' + ffRec.id + '\";})'
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return{
        beforeLoad : beforeLoad
    }
});
```